# passing an array (" without convert to Json object" ) through ajax in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**Controller  Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadList(List<NewList> list) {
    return Json(list);
}
```

**Javascript Array object**

```
var List = [];
List.push({ Id: 1, Name: "A" });
List.push({ Id: 2, Name: "B" });
```

**Ajax call**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "@Url.Action("LoadList")",
    data: { list: List },
    datatype: 'json',
    traditional:true,
    success: function (data) {}
}
```

It is hitting the action but the property values of Id is 0 and Name is null.

Comment: You need the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` option, and you need to stringify the data - `data: JSON.stringify({ list: List }),`

Comment: i want to  post Javascript  array object without converting to Json.

Comment: Why (and what difference do you think it makes)? If you don't want to stringify it, build the data correctly - `{ [0].Id: 1, [0].Name: 'A', [1].Id: 2, [1].Name: 'B' }`

Comment: Actually  i want to  submit AntiForgerytoken with  array data.  so we cant stringyfy  AntiForgerytoken .   -  {  _RequestVerificationToken :token,  list =List }

Comment: Then add that to the object as well. - `__RequestVerificationToken: $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()` But that suggests you have a form, so why are you not just serializing the form? Why are you manually generating these values?

Comment: Actually i want to send AntiForgeryToken  with array of data.  so we can't stringify  AntiForgeryToken.                                                                           **data : {_RequestVerificatinToken :  token  , list:List }**

Comment: // action method                                                                                                                **[HttpPost]                                                        [ValidateantiforgeryToken]                                                                                                 
public JsonResult LoadList(List<NewList> list) {
    return Json(list);
}**